# Numpy / Octave 3d plot: order of input data points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, octave

Haven't done much interpolation and new to numpy / matplotlib. I'm trying to generate a relatively smooth, interpolated surface like the one in [this demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html). In fact I'm just taking my data and substituting it for the example data that is used in the demo.

From the commandline, here's what this looks like, where mat1, mat2, and mat3 are my data:

```
>>> from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mat1
array([[ 1.        ,  1.13953488,  1.08139535,  1.1744186 ],
   [ 1.        ,  0.93617021,  0.93617021,  1.03191489],
   [ 1.        ,  0.94117647,  0.8627451 ,  1.01960784],
   [ 1.        ,  1.10416667,  1.11458333,  1.19791667]])
>>> mat2
array([[ 1.        ,  1.03121019,  1.02802548,  1.01783439],
   [ 1.        ,  0.92777778,  0.93253968,  1.0952381 ],
   [ 1.        ,  1.02673797,  0.93649733,  1.06550802],
   [ 1.        ,  0.91153846,  1.04871795,  1.04166667]])
>>> mat3
array([[ 1.        ,  0.97612732,  1.27851459,  1.22811671],
   [ 1.        ,  1.09747292,  1.11191336,  1.20216606],
   [ 1.        ,  1.17708333,  1.20138889,  1.25      ],
   [ 1.        ,  0.94708995,  1.20634921,  1.10846561]])
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
>>> ax.plot_wireframe(mat1, mat2, mat3, rstride=1, cstride=1)
<mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3DCollection object at 0x7fee30fc0050>
>>> plt.show()
```

And I get something jumbled that looks like [image: jumbled plots]

Is this due to the ordering of my data points (i.e., that the points in mat1 and mat2 are non-monatonic and therefore the line between successive data points jumps around)? I was having the same issues in GNU Octave, which is why I'm trying python. If that's not the problem, what is?

Comment: All data points are automatically connected to the adjacent points in the input with a straight line. You would need to order your points differently and fit an interpolating spline to get a smoother plot.

Comment: Is this always the case, or are there some functions which will handle this for me?  It seems like a non-trivial task.  (Maybe not on a set of 4x4 matrices, but my actual data sets are bigger).

Comment: Yes. How is the function supposed to automatically infer the "correct" ordering of your points otherwise?

Comment: If I knew, I would be writing the code to do it right now :P

Comment: I think your data needs to be regularly spaced and organised. Have you tried to interpolate your data into a regular grid? You can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` ( http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html )

Comment: @DavidWinchester I think that's the answer I was looking for, thank you.